# How to zip generated lists when random lists return empty, using itertools and fillvalue?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, python-itertools

I am trying to zip together multiple lists that contain 10 values. The lists are created by an iterator. Sometimes, the lists generated contain less than 10 values or even 0 values. Thus, I sometimes run into the problem of trying to zip together a list of 10 values with a list of 0 values, or even a list of 0 values with another list of 0 values. I am trying to get python to recognize a list with 0 values and to then fill that list with 0s. This is what I have (the second URL is the problem):

```
import grequests
import json
import time
import itertools

urls3 = [
        #'https://api.livecoin.net/exchange/order_book?currencyPair=RBIES/BTC&depth=5',
        'https://api.livecoin.net/exchange/order_book?currencyPair=REE/BTC&depth=5',
        #'https://api.livecoin.net/exchange/order_book?currencyPair=RLT/BTC&depth=5',
]
requests = (grequests.get(u) for u in urls3)
responses = grequests.map(requests)
#CellRange("B28:DJ48").clear()
def make_column(catalog_response, name):
        column = []
        catalog1 = list(itertools.izip_longest(catalog_response.json()[name][0:5], fillvalue='0 '))
        #catalog1 = catalog_response.json()[name][0:5]
        print(catalog1)
        #quantities1, rates1 = list(itertools.izip_longest(*catalog1,fillvalue='0.0001'))    #uncomment for print #2
        #quantities1, rates1 = zip(*catalog1)    #uncomment for print #2
        print(quantities1)
```

Printing out `catalog1` for only the second link results in the following output:

```
[]
[([u'0.00000001', u'9907729.00000000'],), ([u'0.00000001', u'44800.00000000'],), ([u'0.00000002', u'8463566.49169284'],), ([u'0.00000002', u'3185222.59932121'],), ([u'0.00000002', u'25000.00000000'],)]
```

As you can see, the first array prints `[]`, its empty. This does not make sense to me. I did a trial run with a simpler example of what I am trying to attempt, and it worked just fine:

```
import itertools

list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
list2 = []

print list(itertools.izip_longest(list1,list2, fillvalue='0'))
```

This output the following:

`[('a', '0'), ('b', '0'), ('c', '0'), ('d', '0'), ('e', '0')]`

I thought that maybe running

```
    `column = []
    catalog1 = list(itertools.izip_longest(catalog_response.json()[name][0:5], fillvalue='0 '))
    #catalog1 = catalog_response.json()[name][0:5]
    #print(catalog1)
    quantities1, rates1 = list(itertools.izip_longest(*catalog1,fillvalue='0'))    #uncomment for print #2
    #quantities1, rates1 = zip(*catalog1)    #uncomment for print #2
    print(quantities1)`
```

might fix the issue. But it returns the following error: `ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack`. I cannot seem to figure out why the empty array is not being filled with zeros like my simpler example. In reality, any method that would populate the empty array with a tupled list of zeros would work for me.  I apologize if this is unclear, I am brand new to coding, and I have spent a considerable amount of time on this project and feel like I am getting lost in the weeds. Any help is appreciated.

Note: This question is directly related to my other question at [How do I get my DataNitro table to either skip over failed iterations or print none to the table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45735106/how-do-i-get-my-datanitro-table-to-either-skip-over-failed-iterations-or-print-n) but I felt like the two questions, though sharing the same end, are distinct.

Comment: I am running Python 2.7, sorry should have said that. When I use `itertools.zip_longest` I get `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'zip_longest'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lst2 = ([[u'0',u'0'],[u'0',u'0'],[u'0',u'0'],[u'0',u'0'],[u'0',u'0']])
catalog1 = catalog_response.json()[name][0:5]
S = catalog1 + lst2
quantities1, rates1 = zip(*S)
```